# Changing font colour in a cell in R dataframe based on comparison with other dataframes

Tags: r, openxlsx

**I have 3 dataframes all of which have same number of rows and columns:**

`mean_df` which stores the mean values

`std_dev_df` which stores the standard deviation values

`sales_value_test` in which I have to color/highlight certain cell values based on condition

**The condition is:**

```
if sales_value_test[i, j] < mean_df[i, j] - 2*std_dev_df[i, j] is TRUE, 
then color metric_alert_test[i, j] as red, else do not color it
```

How can I do this in R?

My code is as follows

```
#Creating Dataframe
 metric_alert_sales <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\126063\\Documents\\ITC\\Metric Alert System\\metric_alert.xlsx",sheet = "sales_trend")
 colnames(metric_alert_sales) <- c("branch","oct-19","nov-19","dec-19","jan-20","feb-20","mar-20","apr-20","may-20","jun-20","jul-20","aug-20","sep-20","oct-20","nov-20","dec-20","jan-21","feb-21","mar-21","apr-21","may-21","jun-21","jul-21","aug-21","sep-21","oct-21","nov-21","dec-21","jan-22","feb-22","mar-22","apr-22","may-22","jun-22","jul-22","aug-22","sep-22")
            
 sales_value_test <- metric_alert_sales %>% select(1,26:37)
 mean_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=25,ncol=13))
 colnames(mean_df) <- c("branch","oct-21","nov-21","dec-21","jan-22","feb-22","mar-22","apr-22","may-22","jun-22","jul-22","aug-22","sep-22")
 mean_df["branch"] <- metric_alert_sales["branch"]
 mean_df <- mean_df %>% relocate(branch,.before = NULL) %>% replace(is.na(.),0)
 std_dev_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=25,ncol=13))
 colnames(std_dev_df) <- c("branch","oct-21","nov-21","dec-21","jan-22","feb-22","mar-22","apr-22","may-22","jun-22","jul-22","aug-22","sep-22")
 std_dev_df["branch"] <- metric_alert_sales["branch"]
 std_dev_df <- std_dev_df %>% relocate(branch,.before = NULL) %>% replace(is.na(.),0)
    
 ##Filling up mean_df and std_dev_df
 for (i in 1:nrow(mean_df))
 {
 for (j in 2:ncol(mean_df))
 {
 mean_df[i,j] <- sum((metric_alert_sales[i,j:(j+23)]))/24
 std_dev_df[i,j] <- sd(metric_alert_sales[i,j:(j+23)])
        
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please provide some reproducible data and your code -- specifically which package you are using to build your table.

Comment: @Phil Just edited the post. Just using readxl to load data into dataframe from excel and used dplyr for a bit of data modification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `conditionalFormatting()` function  from `openxlsx` package to change the font in the cells that meet a condition.

Because you don't provide a reproducible data, here is a simple mock data that look similar to yours. I add a column `check` to show the rows that meet or don't meet the condition you have set, which is :
`sales_value_test[i, j] < mean_df[i, j] - 2*std_dev_df[i, j]`.

```
dat = structure(list(mean_df = c(101L, 137L, 123L, 161L, 105L), std_dev_df = c(13L, 
14L, 10L, 18L, 20L), sales_value_test = c(90, 65, 85, 70, 92), 
    check = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
dat

  mean_df std_dev_df sales_value_test check
1     101         13               90 FALSE
2     137         14               65  TRUE
3     123         10               85  TRUE
4     161         18               70  TRUE
5     105         20               92 FALSE
```

```
library(openxlsx)
your_table = createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(your_table,"Sales_Data")
writeData(your_table,"Sales_Data",dat)
conditionalFormatting(your_table, "Sales_Data",
     cols = 3,
     rows = 2:6, 
     rule = "C2:C6 < A2:A6 - 2*(B2:B6)", 
     style = createStyle(fontColour = "red"))
saveWorkbook(your_table, "sales_data.xlsx")
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this solution is that, I would have to explicitly specify the excel cells which I want colored. What I need is that the the coloring should happen in dataframe itself and I can download it in the same way.